# Dialogflow isn't recognizing contractions

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using the v1 REST API to upload intents, but it seems like it's not training the model to recognize any variations of user input (even slight).

For example...

In user says list: "Who is your son?"

User's actual input is "Who’s your son?" but it's not matched to the intent.

Is this expected? I shouldn't have to include every possible phrase variation, right? I feel like the same thing is happening on other intents, too. It just doesn't feel "smart" and seems to only use hard matching on phrases.

Maybe there is a flag that I need to set when I upload...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what api.ai does is it tries to match `user-entered query` with `user says` in your intent & find how much percent of `user-entered query` matches with `user says`. If it is greater than or equal threshold that you have set in your agent's ML settings then only you will get responses from that intent otherwise fallback intent will be called.

Now, coming to your question, you should train your bot for each possible queries but not for queries that slightly differ from each other like in your case you have user says as `Who is your son?` & user-entered query is `who's your son?`. I tried the same at my end & I got the response. Please check snaps below.

[image]
[image]

I guess something else might have gone wrong at your end, possibly you have `disabled ML` from your intent as shown in snap above. When you `disable ML`, api.ai tries to find an exact match between `user-entered query` & `user says` & so I think, it might not be answering you.

Comment: I owe you a beer! I can't believe it, but if you use the API to create intents, it has ML off by default. I just needed to add `auto:true` to my json